# Ubuntu 19.10: No sound (speakers or headphones) on Asus Zenbook UX533FTC

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, asus

Some weeks ago I bought a new [Asus Zenbook UX533FTC](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-15-UX533FTC/specifications/) with preinstalled Windows 10. The sound worked fine until I  reinstalled Ubuntu on the PC.

---

For deciding this problem I:

1. Uppdated BIOS version to the newest;
2. Reinstalled ALSA with this commands:

   - sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
   - sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
   - sudo alsa force-reload.
3. Installed pavucontrol which says that sound works fine;
4. Updated kernel from 5.3.0 to 5.5.5

But... Nothing helped.

Also the sound doesn't work in LiveUSB with Ubuntu 19.10/18.04 and with installed 18.04.

How may I proceed with solving this problem?

Comment: Did you test your laptop by booting from a LiveUSB with Ubuntu 19.10? If so, before you did the Ubuntu installation, did the sound work from the LiveUSB? If it did not, did you try booting from Ubuntu 18.04 and test for sound then? Please click [edit] and expand the question with your answers; please don't put your response in a Comment.

Comment: done, do you know what it can be?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Asus Zenbook UX430UA, all you have to do, every time sound doesnt work put your laptop on Sleep Mode and the sound will work!

For headphones, try this: edit `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` (I think on some computers, it may be just alsa.conf) and insert this as the last line:

`options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mode`